# Neo4j Client And Not Query

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

How do I create this query using `Neo4jClient`.

```
MATCH (keanu:Person)-[:KNOWS*2]->(fof)
WHERE keanu.name = "Keanu Reeves"
AND NOT((keanu)-[:KNOWS]-(fof))
RETURN DISTINCT fof.name;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? The docs at https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki/cypher should give you all information you need.

Comment: I checked that but i am not getting an idea how to apply a And Not Clause in Neo4jClient.

Comment: Thanks Stefan for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a class like:

```
public class Person
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Your query would look like this:

```
client.Cypher
    .Match("(keanu:Person)-[:KNOWS*2]->(fof)")
    .Where((Person keanu) => keanu.Name == "Keanu Reeves")
    .AndWhere("NOT ((keanu-[:KNOWS]-(fof)))")
    .ReturnDistinct(fof => fof.As<Person>().Name);
```

I'm answering mainly as I think the docs do lack a little around using `NOT`, but Stefan is right - the docs do contain most of the info you need - and you do need to show what you've tried, otherwise we're unsure as to what bit you're struggling with.

Comment: Thank's Chris it works, I just Start exploring Neo4j & the client library past week , i was trying there sample query provided on Neo4j with Neo4jClient and stuck on it t.